# What will be a good way to compute a hash of an Avro schema?

Tags: hash, schema, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Consider having separate schema registries for each stage like Dev, Test and Prod.

Then same schema would have different globally unique identifier of the schema in each registry.

The idea is to have stable invariant identifier of a schema across all stages (where the schema was registered/evolved) – a computed hash of the schema content.

What will be a good way to compute such hash? Choosing a specific hash algorithm is not a question here – schema transformation is probably the question: should doc-strings be removed, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Avro specification actually talks about this in the section about the parsing canonical form: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Parsing+Canonical+Form+for+Schemas

That form does say that fields like `doc` should be removed and specifies the order of attributes and other things to make all the schemas consistent.